# Horizontal scrollview auto scroll if textInput text is long enough

Tags: android, react-native, scrollview, horizontalscrollview, react-native-textinput

I've create a tab application with a paging horizontal scroll view has 3 pages like this

```
<ScrollView
   showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
   style={{ flex: 1 }}
   contentContainerStyle={{ height: '100%' }}
   pagingEnabled
   horizontal>
          <View style={{ width, backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
            <TextInput style={{ width, backgroundColor: '#FFF', height: 100 }} />
          </View>
          <View style={{ width, backgroundColor: 'green' }} />
          <View style={{ width, backgroundColor: 'blue' }} />
        </ScrollView>
```

As you can see, in the first tab, there's an TextInput, if you enter a long text (about ~50 characters), the scrollview auto scroll and break the UI (see image below)
The issue only happen on low version Android (5.1, 4.4, 4.2), works well on high version and on iOS
[image]

Comment: Hi there, I am also facing the same issue, please do let me know if you found a solution for this. Appreciated!

Comment: It worked for me when i mark textinput as multiline={true}

Comment: but I just want one line input text, can't find the solution :3

Comment: This is a known and reported an issue in react-native. I have gone through forums as well. For now, you will have to make multiline={true} and manage your self that it should not grow.

Comment: @maphongba008: please let me know if you have the answer. It has been a year or more now but I am still facing the issue. react-native 0.61.5. Kinda sad

Comment: @LuongTruong now I only support Android 6 and higher =))

Comment: @maphongba008: what a nice strategy! =))